# OnMouseDown() null reference exception

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onmousedown

```
public class TowerNode : MonoBehaviour {

public bool IsShopOpen=false;

//Z position
public Vector3 positionOffSet;

//colors
public Color hoverColor;
private Color startColor;

//GameObjects
public GameObject turret;

//shop
public Shop shop;

//Build Manager
BuildManager buildManager;

void Start()
{
    rend=GetComponent<Renderer>();
    startColor = rend.material.color;
    buildManager = BuildManager.instance;
    shop = GetComponent<Shop>();
}


//When mouse is on the turret node
public void OnMouseDown()
{    
    Debug.Log("Mouse is Down");
    bool IsShopOpen  = true;
    if (IsShopOpen == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("shop is open");
        shop.onEnable();
    }

    if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
    {          
        return;
    }
    if (!buildManager.CanBuild)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (turret != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Cant Build Here!!!");
        return;
    }       

    buildManager.BuildTurretOn(this);

}
```

the other script of the shop is this:

```
public class Shop : MonoBehaviour
{
public TurretBlueprint Archery;
public TurretBlueprint Treb;
public TurretBlueprint Workamp;
public TurretBlueprint Barracks;

public Button Archeryy;
public Button Trebb;
public Button WorkCampp;
public Button Barrackss;

BuildManager buildManager;


void Start()
{
    buildManager = BuildManager.instance;
    disableAllButtons();
    //OnEnable();
}

public void SelectArchery()
{
    buildManager.SelectTurretToBuild(Archery);
    Debug.Log("archery!!!!");

}
public void SelectTreb()
{
    buildManager.SelectTurretToBuild(Treb);
    Debug.Log("Treb!!!!");
}
public void SelectWorkamp()
{
    buildManager.SelectTurretToBuild(Workamp);
    Debug.Log("Work Camp!!!!");
}
public void SelectBarracks()
{
    buildManager.SelectTurretToBuild(Barracks);
    Debug.Log("Barracks!!!!");
}


public void onEnable()
{
    Archeryy.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    Trebb.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    WorkCampp.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    Barrackss.gameObject.SetActive(true);

}

public void disableAllButtons()
{
    Archeryy.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    Trebb.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    WorkCampp.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    Barrackss.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

}
```

I need when i click on the game object that the shop will open the sop got few buttons under it, but it gives me:

> "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   TowerNode.OnMouseDown () (at Assets/Scripts/TowerNode.cs:51)
>   UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32)"

and I don't understand why.

Comment: what is `BuildManager.instance`? it appears as though buildManager is null.

Comment: the problem isnt there this is my build manager, 
its in my " 
shop.onEnable();"

Comment: I don't think this will solve your problem, but as an FYI, OnEnable() is a built in unity function. I would avoid using it as your function name.

Comment: iv changed the name of the function and it still not working doing the same problem

Comment: iv changed the name of the function and it still not working.

Comment: if i put the onEnable() in //onEnable();
it working but the UI wont open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting implies that an object in the `OnMouseDown` function is null when executed:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object TowerNode.OnMouseDown () (at Assets/Scripts/TowerNode.cs:51)

You should look at ine 51 of `TowerNode.cs` and ascertain what can be null on that line. Could `shop` or `buildManager` be null? Perhaps this event is firing before you have initialised your `TowerNode` object.

It seems you are trying to access a component (`Shop`) from a completely unrelated GameObject. If you want all of your `TowerNode` objects to reference the `Shop` then you could use [GameObject.Find](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html). This isn't really recommended though; it seems like there is a better way to link these two objects but I am unsure of your use case.

Comment: shop.onEnable(); this is the problem for some reason can u help me understand why its not working?

Comment: Check to see if your shop when you are grabbing the component is null, or if any of its underlying objects used in onEnable are null. Could it be that the button itself maybe is in a state which makes it null?

Comment: You set the reference to `shop` in the `Start` function of `TowerNode`, this implies one of the following: a) the `Start` function is not called, meaning your `TowerNode` object hasn't been initialised. b) there is no `Shop` on the game object. Is the `Shop` component added on the game object next to the `TowerNode` component?

Comment: iv checked and start had been called i mean its working.
and there is Shop on the game object its UI panel that have buttons in it.

Comment: if i put the onEnable() in //onEnable();
it working but the UI wont open

Comment: When `Start` is called is the `shop` object value being set or is it still null after the `GetComponent` call? If it is null then the `TowerNode` component doesn't know where to get the `Shop` component from. It seems that `Shop` might be a completely different GameObject in the hierarchy?

Comment: Sorry for my question im kind of a begginer how do i check if he got it?

Comment: You could step over the code while debugging and inspect the `shop` object after the call. Alternatively you can null check the object and add a Debug.Log() if it is null.

Comment: its finding the shop, like the shop is getting initialize

Comment: The shop might be getting initialised but in `TowerNode` you are trying to grab a reference; `shop = GetComponent<Shop>();`. If the `GetComponent` call cannot find a `Shop` object, then the field `shop` in `TowerNode` will be null. I have edited my answer to include some extra information.

Comment: what should i type in the GameObject.find();
cause when i type shop or Shop it doing an error
i think that is the solution though cause it different game object

Comment: Find looks for the object by name, so you will need to pass it the name of the GameObject in the hierarchy that has the 'Shop' component on it.

Comment: iv tried to put Shop or shop and its giving me an error like i cant type it there.

Comment: The function takes a 'string' argument, you need to put quotes around whatever you pass in. Remember you are passing the name of the GameObject that the 'Shop' component is on.

Comment: iv put the GameObject.Find("Shop");
in the start method and even tried it in the OnMouseDown both didnt work.

Comment: I'm afraid without knowing your hierarchy it's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. I think perhaps a greater understanding of how game objects can communicate would help you. This tutorial should help you; https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/how-communicate-between-scripts-and-gameobjects.